# Hex and Int bitwise operation confict

Tags: kotlin, bit-manipulation

Why in Kotlin bitwise operation is not possible with 4-byte hex and Int?

At the same time, there is no problem in Java

As far as I know, in JVM `int` takes 4 bytes.

```kotlin
// Kotlin
val num = 0
val n = 0xff000000 or num    // <-- 'num' ERROR
```

```java
// Java
int num = 0;
int n = 0xff000000 | num;    // <-- 'num' OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0xFF000000` is a Long, not an Int. It's outside the Int range since it is using 32 bits to represent a positive number, but Int only uses 31 bits for the number, and one bit for the sign. Any six-digit hexadecimal number where the first digit is greater than 7 requires 32 bits to represent the number, so it is interpreted as a Long.

Kotlin doesn't do implicit number conversions like Java because they can easily lead to obscure bugs. You have to manually convert it to an Int.

```
val num = 0
val n = 0xff000000.toInt() or num
```